# Python LangChain CSV Agent need help in Chart Image saving

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, langchain

I am pretty new in LangChain, playing with Langchain's CSV Agent. It is giving me the desired result. Look at the attached image

[image]

Now, I want to use the code outside of Google Colab. However, in the python script, it is giving me the text, but as expected, no figure. How can I extract the figure from Langchain's CSV Agent if any? I need your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just screen shot the chart for external usage?

Or are you looking to be able to edit the look and feel?

Answer (score 0):

try to import pyplot and show the plot after the call to ask:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
ask("Display agent's performancebased on number of bill minutes, sort the data in desc and create a bar graph")
plt.show()
```